# Magento 2 Google Analytics code cannot be found in FE html

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I have set up in M2 Google analytics code and it cannot be found in FE html pages.

Comment: Can you provide more information.

Comment: In M2 vandor folder there is google analytics module that add block to FE page. But it isn't displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable cookie restriction:

General -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings -> Cookie Restriction Mode -> No

Comment: This worked for us, Magento 2.1.6

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup or configure GoogleAnalytics in Magento admin as per the image in order to get it work.

[image]

You can find the code in below path.

/vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/templates/ga.phtml

Reference [link](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/google-analytics)

For your comment, I enable Google analytics, after remove cache i able to see this code in view page source.

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


ga('create', '54894136498cvbcb4565c4vb98', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

//]]>
</script>
```

> Whether it is working or not is depending upon your tool
>   configuration.

Comment: Already did. Nothing changed.

Comment: Please check the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Magento 2 EE **and** have Google Tag Manager enabled along with Google Analytics, the default.xml of the Magento Google Tag Manager module actually *suppresses* the inclusion of GA/UA.

```
<!-- Remove Magento_GoogleAnalytics -->
<referenceBlock name="google_analytics" remove="true" />
```

I suspect the thinking is that if you are using GTM, you would be using it to do the GA/UA inclusion instead of including GA/UA separately. Yet, the administration shows the GA/UA configuration giving the "hint" that GA/UA will be available and configured by Magento, not via GTM on the Google end of things.