# Magento2.2 - Send event to Google Analytics in a .phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, google-analytics

I have tried to send an event in .phtml file using

```
<script>ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: '...',
    eventAction: '...',
    eventLabel: '...'
});</script>
```

But Browser Console says that ga is undefined, Please help me how can I send an event to Google Analytics.

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Hello, have you looked at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134765/magento-2-google-analytics-code-cannot-be-found-in-fe-html ?

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: @ColdFridge I don't think so this question belongs to above link.